# PHP/MySQL Average based on contents of Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the following array:

```
array(
    a => 6.75,
    b => 5.45,
    c => 8.76,
    d => 7.76,
    e => 8.16,
    f => 2.76,
    g => 4.67,
    h => 9.01,
    i => 5.42,
)
```

What I am looking to achieve is to `average` the `top quartile`.

In essence I need to order the array in `descending` order, then calculate what the `top quartile` will be (i.e. 9 (the numbers of elements in the array) x 25% = 2.25 rounded down to 2, so it would be the first two numbers that need to be averaged).

It's this figure I'm looking for.

I'm struggling to figure out how to achieve this and whether it's best to do this within PHP or via a query to the MySQL database.

Any and all advice, feedback and suggestions welcomed.

Comment: http://rpbouman.blogspot.co.uk/2008/07/calculating-percentiles-with-mysql.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily in PHP :

```
$array = array(
a => 6.75,
b => 5.45,
c => 8.76,
d => 7.76,
e => 8.16,
f => 2.76,
g => 4.67,
h => 9.01,
i => 5.42,
);

arsort($array); // Order the array in descending order
$top_quartile = floor(count($array)/4); // Calculate top quartile
$array = array_slice($array, 0, $top_quartile); // Keep only the top quartile values

$total = 0;
foreach($array as $value) {
    $total += $value;
}
$average = $total/$top_quartile;

echo $average;
```

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, thanks - will review and come back to you.

Answer (score 2):

It's going to be tough to do this in MySQL, because you can't have a variable `LIMIT` directly.

However, it would certainly be most efficient to do it there, rather than transferring all of the data to PHP when you only need a bit of it.

So, with that in mind, try this algorithm:

- `SELECT COUNT(*)` from your table to get the number of rows
- Divide that number of rows by 4, call that `$quartile_count`
- Now you need a nested query:

  ```
  SELECT AVG(`column_name`)
  FROM (
      SELECT `column_name`
      FROM `table_name`
      ORDER BY `column_name` DESC
      LIMIT $quartile_count
  ) `tmp`
  ```

  This is because `LIMIT` must be applied first, before the aggregate `AVG` function.

Comment: Thanks for this, will test and come back shortly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = array(
    'a' => 6.75,
    'b' => 5.45,
    'c' => 8.76,
    'd' => 7.76,
    'e' => 8.16,
    'f' => 2.76,
    'g' => 4.67,
    'h' => 9.01,
    'i' => 5.42,
);
rsort($a);
$sum = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($a) / 4; ++$i){
    $sum += $a[$i];
}
$result = $sum / $i;
echo $result;
```

Comment: Cheers, will review and test and post a reply shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Done in a single piece of SQL:-

```
SELECT AVG(some_column)
FROM
(
    SELECT some_column, @seq:=@seq+1 AS seq
    FROM
    (
        SELECT some_column
        FROM some_values
        ORDER BY some_column DESC
    ) sub0
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @seq:=0) sub1
) sub2
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS all_count
    FROM some_values
) sub3
WHERE sub3.all_count / 4 > sub2.seq
```

This has one sub query to get the rows in descending order, then adds a sequence number to it, then cross joins the results of that with a sub query that gets the total number of records, has a WHERE clause to eliminate all but the top quarter and then uses AVG() to get the average.

More done out of interest than as a practical solution as I suspect it will perform poorly. Only really useful if you require it as a datasource that must be a single query.

Comment: Thanks for that @Kickstart - again, I'll try this out and see what is working best from a performance aspect.  Great that it is all in SQL but as you say, not sure how it will perform.  Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete code of your problem.

```
$rs = mysql_query("select count(column name) as total from table");
$result = mysql_fetch_row($rs);
$avg = floor($result[0]/4);

$rs = mysql_query("select column name from table order by column name desc limit 0,".$avg);
$total = 0;
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
     $total += $result['column name'];
}
echo $total/mysql_num_rows($rs);
```